# javafx MediaPlayer- getting the next song

Tags: javafx, media-player

When I start my mediaplayer, and click the next-song button, it starts at the first song and goes down the list as intended. But if I start the program, double-click an mp3 file to play it, then click the next-song button, the first song in the list plays, not the mp3 after the mp3 I double clicked.

```
btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) ->
{

    if(doubleClicked)
    {
        player.stop();
        media = new Media(rowData.toURI().toString()); // needs to go to next song
        player = new MediaPlayer(media);
        player.play();
        return;
    }
    if(music.hasNext())
    {
        try
        {               
            player.stop();
            media = new Media(music.next());
            player = new MediaPlayer(media);

            player.play();

            lbl.setText(media.getSource());   
        }
        catch(MediaException a)
        {
            System.out.println("Unsupported Format");
        }
    }

});
```

`rowData` is the mp3 file when double clicked. I've tried a bunch of things but nothing seems to work. I have my own data structure for this, but its pretty much the same as the built in `Iterator` and `ArrayList` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't adjust the `Iterator`'s position according to the new position in the playlist. Given the index of the item clicked by the user you can simply replace the `Iterator` by a new one using [`List.listIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#listIterator-int-).

Here's an simplified example using a `ListView` and `String`s that are displayed in a label:

```
private Iterator<String> songIterator;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    ObservableList<String> songs = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Song 1", "Song 2", "Song 3", "Song 4");

    // start with first song
    songIterator = songs.iterator();
    Label songLabel = new Label(songIterator.next());
    ListView<String> lv = new ListView(songs);

    MultipleSelectionModel<String> selectionModel = lv.getSelectionModel();

    lv.setCellFactory(t -> new ListCell<String>() {

        {
            setOnMouseClicked(evt -> {
                if (evt.getButton() == MouseButton.PRIMARY && evt.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    evt.consume();
                    // update label
                    songLabel.setText(getItem());
                    // iterator should return next item next
                    songIterator = songs.listIterator(selectionModel.getSelectedIndex()+1);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty ? null : item);
        }

    });

    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Next");
    btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
        if (songIterator.hasNext()) {
            songLabel.setText(songIterator.next());
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(songLabel, lv, btn));

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```